# Area 51's logo is a low-res raster

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, area-51, logo

Area 51's logo uses a raster image, which is low-res at larger displays:

[image]

whereas Area 51 Discussions uses a vector graphic, which does not pixelate no matter the display:

[image]

Shouldn't Area 51 use a vector logo too?

Comment: Should? Yes. Would? Don't think so. (aka development-wise, Area 51 is "frozen", they don't spend any more time on it, it was mentioned several times in comments from SE developers)